# Merge (concatenate) files with ffmpeg, specifying start time for each file

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-conversion

I have bunch of audio files, e. g.:

- **audio001.wav**,
- **audio002.wav**,
- **audio003.wav** etc.

I need to merge all files together specifying start position for every file, like **audio001.wav** should start on 00:00:03, **audio002.wav** on 00:00:10 and so on.

If there is free space between files, it must be filled with silence. Or if files are overlapping, I don't care, because all positions and lengths are mathematically pre-arranged and overlaps will be small anyway (like 1-5 milliseconds, or rather 1-2 milliseconds).

Is there way to do such composing with ffmpeg? Or some another command line utility?

Comment: The "simple" way to do this is to generate various length "silent" audio files files with ffmpeg and then just concantenate them together with your regular audio files in the correct order.

Comment: No it's too rough... But I found some specific workaround that doesn't include cutting/joining.